# Error while authorizing the salesforce using JWT

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

- sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid **** --jwtkeyfile **** --username **** --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
  ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: Error authenticating with JWT config due to: request to http://test.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.salesforce.com
  request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.salesforce.com
  request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND login.salesforce.com